# Using PHP to add a field in MySQL if it doesn' texist

Tags: php, mysql

I have a submission script that I wrote in PHP.  It is used by multiple surveys at our organization.  The surveys are created by other users.  When they submit to the script, PHP puts the data into the appropriate table in MySQL.  The error that I run into sometimes is that the user(s) update the form.  They add a field, or rename an input and the script doesn't account for it since it expects everything to be the same.  So, I am trying to find a way to make it accomodate for when a new field is added.  Here is what I have:

```
 if( mysql_num_rows( mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '".$survey."'"))){

    echo "table exists";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $survey . ";";
    $result = mysql_query($sql)
        or die(mysql_error());
    $i=0;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result));{
        echo $row[0];
        foreach($_POST as $k => $v){
            $i++;
            if($k != $row[$i]){
                $query = "ALTER TABLE " . $survey . " ADD " . $k . " VARCHAR(100);";
                mysql_query($query)
                    or die(mysql_error());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am used to doing while loops in JS, so I don't know if using i works here (actually, I know it doesn't work... because it doesn't work...).  What I am trying to say is that if a key doesn't match a current field name, then add it to the table.  How can I return $row correctly?

When I submit to the script it says:
Duplicate column name 'V4'

I have echo $row[0] but it returns a 1.  Which is the is the int used in the primary key for the for the first record.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? Does it show you a blank screen? Is there an error message?

Comment: Nice SQL injection holes... plus giving a MySQL account that's used in public-facing code alter privs on a table is just TOTALLY begging for your server to get ground under someone's foot. Better read up on [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.net) before you get shot in the foot.

Comment: Isn't it more convenient to use `SHOW COLUMNS FROM your_table` ?

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Using Show columns helped a lot.

This was just an internal test, so I was working on getting it to work with simple code before I used sprintf and escapes.  Thank you for the advise.

Answer (score 3):

You have a `;` at the end of your while loop declaration that shouldn't be there.  Not sure if that is causing the problem as you don't say what the above code *does* do.  Update the question if the `;` is not the issue.

Your while loop declaration should look like this: `while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {`

Also, as Marc B so diplomatically put it in a comment to your question, you should be escaping any user input that goes directly into a query.

The easiest way to do this is to use `$survey = mysql_real_escape_string($survey)`, before your first use of `$survey`, as a start or switch to PDO/MySQLi and use [input binding (prepared statements)](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).  [Here are the prepared statements docs for PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).  More can, and should, be done to protect yourself, but the above is a good start.